# Can read Data from mysql database but cant write data into the database Using PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have a PHP 5.6 project, when I run it on localhost in windows/xampp it works perfectly fine.But when I use it in ubuntu/apache it connects to the db,reads data from the db perfectly but doesnt write data.

I know its reading data perfectly cause it verify's user credentials stored in db for login and displays user info, but it dosen't perform any data insertion activity, upon that I dont get any error too, please help !

github -https://github.com/neelgeek/Paathshala-Management

***Update -***
I have somewhat figured out the problem, it seems there is some issue with mysqli statements used in the PHP files for Ajax calls in the project. I tested a test file with PDO statements and its working perfectly. Will update soon.

Comment: Does the user have INSERT/UPDATE privileges on the DB/tables?

Comment: How do you witness that the inserts/updates fail ?  Some logs maybe ? be specific.

Comment: @jcorry yes, I am using the root user,it has all privileges.

Comment: YvesLwBorg, I checked apache and phpmyadmin logs, I didnt find any errors too.  I works perfectly on windows but not on ubuntu.

Comment: Can you share the insert/update statements that are used? So you have a 5.6 project on XAMPP, but what are the PHP/MySQL versions on Ubuntu vs. XAMPP? ... seems that there is something different between the two (apparently), but there's no way we can help without more details. Though the title claims PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu, is this true? ... the question seems to imply that the XAMPP side, at least, has 5.6.

Comment: No the PHP verison is not 5.6 on Ubuntu. Its 7.0. But if verison would have caused the problem, it would have thrown error. It wouldn't have allow me to read the data right ? The fact that I can read the data is that the sql queries are getting executed. @PaulT

Comment: @NeelBhave: ... yes, on the surface that would seem true, but since you have not provided any code, we can't tell how/if you check the query handling (if any) after the insert/update calls. I also have Ubuntu with 7.0, but I'm not transitioning from a 5.6 perspective. However, know that there are likely differences between MySQL versions on the two machines as well.

Comment: Ok fine. I cant actually paste the whole code as it is a very big project. I will post the link to the code of the function here which executes the query.  
 [link(https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uHUmhsDhAFYXKyLuMAL9nQjy-my0-EY5lRENOwD53cA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @NeelBhave: Sorry for the delay, should have added the `@person` syntax for inbox notifications as I'm just now checking a few old comments. Anyway, do you make direct calls to the `setquery()` function for the `insert` and `update` queries? I see how your `getData()` function does the `select` queries, so how do you do the other queries?

Comment: @PaulT. I have many other classes and those classes call the setquery function through the object of the Class file. There are different classes for different functionalities in the project.

Comment: @NeelBhave: ... I get that aspect, but it's just not clear why only inserts are not working without having more detail/info? We do not expect anyone to post their entire code base here, as only [a mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary to pose the problem. Anything more will likely be TL;DR for anyone to bother helping.

Comment: @PaulT. As far as code is concerned it is perfectly fine and tested. I have used the same code for another project too. The code as I said is perfectly working in Windows/Xampp but not Ubuntu. The Context of my question is whether anyone has come across such issue in Ubuntu or is there a setting in Ubuntu that has to be done especially while setting up the apache server for PHP. I have not posted this question for a bug in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
So after 3 hours of debugging each and every query, I found out the solution.

***Reason 1 -***
My version of MySQL didn't allow me to keep columns with no default value **unattended in a query**. That means I had to specify each and every column in my query even if it was blank in a particular situation.
***Solution -*** I had to go to each table and change the default value of each column which would be sometimes not specified in a query to some default value, mostly NULL worked for me.

***Reason 2-***
At some places I had not used **`<column-name>`** syntax, hence it was throwing an internal error, but as I was using phpmyadmin,I was not able to see the errors as phpmyadmin as no clear logging.
**Solution-**
Just make sure your SQL syntax is proper.

**Conclusion-**Finally I found that the main reason behind such errors is the SQL version, as each version has its own set of rules.

Thanks everyone who helped me in the comments :)

Comment: I think you are mistaken on what is happening here. If you had given actual examples of your query we could have help you understand why. There is no such thing as an SQL database which is going to be able to guess which columns contain which data. Which is why you need to either specify all values for every column or specify the column names you are going to fill and then specify their appropriate values.

Comment: I had specified the column names but, my syntax was wrong. At some places, I didn't use the " ` " symbol before and after the column name and table name.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issues my problem was with the primary key. It was not set to **AUTOINCREMENT**.

[image]